# Legends colors are not proper in axlsx stacked bar chart

Tags: ruby, axlsx

Hi i am using axlsx for generate excel file in rails

In stacked group barchat legends colors are not proper.

Its not taking my color.

```
sheet.add_chart(Axlsx::Bar3DChart, :start_at => "G2", :end_at => "O15", :title => "#{business_unit}",:barDir => :col,:grouping=> :stacked) do |chart|
    chart.add_series :data => sheet["B3:B6"], :labels => sheet["A3:A6"], :title => sheet["B2"], :colors => ['222','222','222','222']
    chart.add_series :data => sheet["C3:C6"], :labels => sheet["A3:A6"], :title => sheet["C2"], :colors => ['ffff00','ffff00','ffff00','ffff00']
    chart.add_series :data => sheet["D3:D6"], :labels => sheet["A3:A6"], :title => sheet["D2"], :colors => ['ff0000','ff0000','ff0000','ff0000']
    chart.add_series :data => sheet["E3:E6"], :labels => sheet["A3:A6"], :title => sheet["E2"], :colors => ['0f52d6','0f52d6','0f52d6','0f52d6']
   end
```

Please see the picture for detail. Its taking default colour not mine
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uFYYK.png)

Answer (score 0):

You specify colors with alpha-channel:

```
#                                      ⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓
:colors => ['ffff00','ffff00','ffff00','ffff00']
```

Either removing it or setting to `1` should fix the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Actually its not taking the labels as legends. Its taking title as legends.So it takes default colors.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, Below working for me

```
:colors => ['FF0000', '00FF00', '0000FF']
```

Comment: Please try with stacked barchat. For stacked barchat its not working.Can you post your code.